# The point of contact between a line with a circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

My question is:

I have a circle of radius 40 and a line which the circle is tangent to. So, if I take a circle of radius 80, do the two circles have the same point of contact? I mean: do they (my circle with radius 40 with my circle with radius 80 ) have the same point of contact??
Thanks beforehand.

Kind regards,
Maryam

Comment: IF the center of both circles is same then the point of contact of bigger circle ( 80 ) is not same as the smaller circle.

Comment: To expand on what SA-255525 said, you would need to specify which points stay in the same place to know which points move.

Answer (score 0):

Call P the point where the line and the circle of radius 40 are tangent. Your circle of radius 80 is tangent to your circle of radius 40 at P if and only if the center of the first is the diametrically opposite point of P in the circle of radius 40.